# Bypassing CORS in 2020

Tags: cors

I am busy testing an API setup on AWS with API gateway this is the first time I have tested an API off a server for a SPA I am developing from my local PC. I therefore never knew about this CORS thing and boy is it frustrating!

Are there any ways to simply bypass this in 2020 because the plugins for Chrome dont work and starting the browser with disable security argument is also not working.

The question is why is this so hard for a developer who wants to work on their local machine to bypass its causing me endless frustration and swearwords I mean seriously really!??! Why does whoever implemented do this? Rant over.

For me the thought of building infrastructure and getting the site up and running on AWS within the same domain is too much of a detour right now when I want to get the page open on my browser on my local pc to call the API.

To make things more frustrating I tried following an outdated guide on AWS docmentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) to disable this and the updated AWS console does not allow wildcards for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" anymore.

What evil things have been done that have caused this paranoia?

Any suggestions?

Comment: i feel the same. such a pain just to test small things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have 2 ways for do that.

1. You have to TEMPORARY bypass CORS-POLICY for make the request from the same origin*:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

And then force the api to use it (in case of NODEJS + EXPRESS):

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

2. You can use [PostMan](https://www.postman.com/) for make the request.

*REMEMBER: As Mozilla dev-forum say "Using the wildcard to allow all sites to access a private API is a bad idea." Remember to turn off this features, once you publish your api!

If it doesn't work, please provide some more details such your api-language, platform ....

P.s. you have the AWS Guide ... it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for feedback. For some reason the AWS setting "took" this morning because last night the AWS console was giving a error in a red bar toast on top saying "wildcards not allowed" this morning it works fine. Very strange. I also managed to find  an older version of chrome that worked.